# How to add percentages and insert the result into different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to provide selling rate and buying rate from the spot rate. At the moment I have a table called **Currency** which holds **[currency_code]** and **[Rate]**.
I also have table called **Transaction** that contains **[Tran_ID]**, **[Buying_rate]** and **[Selling_rate]**
I would like to add 3 % from the **[Rate]** and store it into the **[Buying_rate]**. I would also like to minus 3% and store it into the **[Selling_rate]**.

[image]

I have looked for tutorials online and I was unable to find any.  I would appreciate lot if a demonstration can be shown.

I have applied the query

```
 insert into Transaction Set 
 Tran_id = 1,
 Buying_Rate = (select (rate + (3*Rate)/100) as ratepos from currency  ),
 Selling_Rate = (select (rate - (3*Rate)/100) as rateneg from currency  )
```

I get this error message =>>> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Table structure of **Transaction**

```
Field        Type    Collation  Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
Tran_ID      int(11)            No  None    auto_increment                          
Buying_Rate  float          No  None                                
Selling_Rate float          No  None
```

Table structure of **currency**

```
Field          Type   Collation     Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
currency_code  varchar(255)   latin1_swedish_ci No                                  
Rate           float                            Yes       NULL
```

On the **Transaction** table its meant to be empty so that the new selling and buying rate get stored in their an example of the output would be

On the **Transaction** table its meant to be empty so that the new selling and buying rate get stored in their an example of the output would be

```
**|Tran_ID|Buying_rate|Selling_Rate| ** 
  | 1     |   1.1842  | 1.1242     |
```

the example above shows the EURO currency the adding of the 3% and the subtracting of 3%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just an idea on how to do it

```
 insert into Transaction Set 
 Trans_id = your_transaction_id ,
 Buying_ID = (select (rate + (3*Rate)/100) as ratepos from Currency 
              where currency_code = 'euro'),
 Selling_ID = (select (rate - (3*Rate)/100) as rateneg from Currency 
               where currency_code = 'euro' )
```

EDIT.

[**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd142/1)

Comment: I am getting this error message 
**#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

>  insert into Transaction Set   Tran_ID = 1,  Buying_Rate  = (select
> (rate + (3*Rate)/100) as ratepos from currency  ),  Selling_Rate =
> (select (rate - (3*Rate)/100) as rateneg from currency  )

Comment: why are you using `>` in my query . this was just an idea on how to do it. if you want to apply it , then please post a sample data of your tables and the wished result after update.then we i can see how it will be

Comment: I have upload the structure of the tables I still don't understand why I keep getting this error message. P.S thanks for your help by the way

Comment: can you make some sample data also ? and wished result please.

Comment: what trans_id should be inserted ? 1 ,2 , 3 ... or should be the name of currency code or what ?

Comment: i edited my answer and added the demo , but your result are wrong if in euro . hope it helps you .

Comment: if you want make insert to all values , just make a loop in php with the variable like that `where currency_code = '$code' `

Comment: Thank you so much for you help it works ,  I am using the database for a Java application

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
Insert into Transaction  
Select Top 1 'Enter Trans_id', (Rate + (3*Rate)/100),(Rate - (3*Rate)/100) From Currency
```